# Can't ignore a file in Mercurial Commit (TortoiseHG)

Tags: version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg, ignore, hgignore

I've been using Mercurial for more than a year. Now, I added a new .Net project to it. I chose to ignore all the BIN / OBJ folders in the Solution folder and everything went well. I used masks to ignore entire folders or the right click -> Ignore command to ignore particular files.

Now, all of the sudden, I can't see the Ignore command any more! Normally, it should appear upon right-clicking a file. It doesn't. I also tried ignoring the file manually by adding this line in the .hgignore file:

```
Client/eTimeKeepLoading.png
```

But all that did was to (as you can see in the image below) mark my .hgignore file for commit, but the damn PNG file is still in the list. What's wrong with this guy? ::- D.

[image: I don't see the "Ignore" command]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's an already-added file. Ignoring only hides files that aren't yet tracked by Mercurial (and you can explicitly `hg add` ignored files if you want). Just revert it, and it'll be hidden.